# How can I add doActivity behavior to a state machine's state in IBM Rhapsody?

Tags: state, uml, state-machine, rhapsody, statechart

I'm new in IBM Rational Rhapsody.
I'm drawing a state diagram using IBM Rational Rhapsody (ver. 8.4.1) for a class that it contains several states.
I can add entry/exit actions to each state easily but I don't know how can I assign a doActivity behavior (the behavior which is run when a state is active) to a state. I think this feature is not supported by IBM Rational Rhapsody. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Bruce Douglass has a special [video "Revenge of the Do Activities"](https://youtu.be/pYdMm3onnbU), where he shows how to add do-activities in Cameo and Rhapsody.

In my view this is a bit of overkill, though. Typically, a "do activity" boils down to a periodic reaction in a given state, which could be modeled simply by an internal transition triggered by a periodic time event. No sub-states are needed.

Comment: as far as I know, by using internal transition, all entry actions to the state is called which is not my case.

Comment: It seems that you might be confusing internal transitions with transitions to self. Internal transitions never cause execution of any exit or entry actions.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.